# How does ASP.NET parse an ASPX file into executable code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ascx

How does ASP.NET parse an .aspx, .ascx or .master file into executable code?

I have a brain and a copy of .NET Reflector, so if someone could tell me where to look, that is sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `TemplateParser` and `TemplateBuilder` classes and their derivatives.

You can download the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) for the .Net framework, which includes comments and will be more readable than Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the asp.net syntax parser (system.web.dll) compilation namespace, and codedom for the language of the file to generate source files. Then compiles them to a dll with the codedom provider places them in the asp.net temporary files dir and loads it.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to learn more on the life cycle is to use the debugger in Visual Studio 2010 and set a break point somewhere. Then show the Call stack (Debug->Windows->Call Stack). Then right click somewhere in the call stack trace and choose "Show External Code". There you can see what's going on in the managed world.

Comment: Actually, that won't help.  No user code is called during this process, so there is nowhere to set a breakpoint.

Comment: I was thinking   `System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr)` for instance, which would be the first call into the managed world. However, that isn't actually an answer.